# Chrome content_script: How to wait for jQuery

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'm writing a small Chrome extension that would have a `content_script`.

It would run on a single domain, I'm trying to improve a site a bit.

I want to use `jQuery` in my content script, but the site also uses `jQuery`, so I cannot simply add jQuery to my extension's `content_script` array.

My `content_script` will

```
"run_at": "document_end"
```

but `jQuery` is not yet loaded.  It's not loaded on `document_idle` either.

So I have to wait for it.

How do I do that?

I've tried doing this:

```
(function() {
    var i = setInterval(function () {
        console.log(typeof jQuery + " " + i);
        if (typeof jQuery != "undefined") {
            console.log("jQuery loaded");
            clearInterval(i);
        } else {
            console.log("jQuery not loaded");
        }
    }, 200);
})();
```

But for some reason `typeof jQuery` is always undefined within that loop.

If I manually `clearInterval`, and check `typeof jQuery` I properly get `"function"`.
(chrome inspector console)

Any ideas?

EDIT:
`content_script`s are special:

> Content scripts are JavaScript files that run in the context of web
>   pages. By using the standard Document Object Model (DOM), they can
>   read details of the web pages the browser visits, or make changes to
>   them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I cannot simply add jQuery to my extension's `content_script` array.

You can and should. Extension variable space is sandboxed, so content scripts cannot access variables from parent's page and vice versa.

Comment: I'm using a `content_script`: Content scripts are JavaScript files that run in the context of web pages. By using the standard Document Object Model (DOM), they can read details of the web pages the browser visits, or make changes to them.

Comment: @Prody They can access DOM, but they cannot access variables and functions. See http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html#execution-environment